# Error { "message": "No userid found in auth token" } in Postman using the Mendeley web API

Tags: postman, mendeley

I am trying to use a GET method in Postman for the endpoint https://api.mendeley.com/search/documents?author=Fallman, but I keep getting the error mentioned in the title. Testing it directly on the API returns an empty list. How can I make it work in Postman? I am using a bearer token.

I have updated the token several times and it hasn't resolved the issue.